# Philips TV constantly disconnects?

Tags: wireless-networking, connection, media-server

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask because it might turn that it's a TV problem but...

So at home I have a Xubuntu 12.10 machine which has a PlexMediaServer installed. A Philips 5500 TV in the  other room connects to the network and scans for a media server. At the beginning I had problems with discovering the server but now it's fine. If I play a movie from the server after about ~30min the connection drops out. I have to restart the TV and to scan again for a media server, which sometimes takes a bit longer.

I want to know is that a problem of the Server (Xubuntu 12.10), the WIFI router (TP-LINK TL-WR702N) or the TV?

Comment: This sounds like what my TV does. My TV has a power saving feature on it which causes it to shut off if it can't find a usable signal to display. When I shut my PC off my TV shuts down as well. This is a good thing. As for why your server keeps dropping the signal... I have no idea. It could be a million things, from a max bandwidth reached setting, a timer setting, or a screen saver. Maybe a Linux person will come in and shine some light on the issue. Look at the bright side though- It's likely not your TV ; )

Comment: Thanks! I really hope it's not my TV because after these ~30min it doesn't turn off, but it says that connection is lost. I really didn't think about the max bandwidth, it sounds reasonable. Timer setting might work if it's a feature of the media server but a screen saver could not be a reason, because I have no monitor attached to the Xubuntu machine and I start XFCE manually (i prefer SSH). Well I will try the max bandwidth option when I get home (tomorrow) :)

Comment: Known problem with 5500 wifi: http://www.supportforum.philips.com/en/showthread.php?24715-5500-Wifi-Issue&highlight=5500